# What power cable to use for motherboard 24 pin or 8 pin where I have both?

Tags: motherboard, power

I have motherboard ASrock H470 with both 24 pins and 8 pins slots for power.
I have power unit which has both 24 pin and 8 pins cables.

Do I have to connect both cables?

Comment: Your motherboard manual should tell you want you need to do.

Comment: Yes, you do need to connect both cables.

Comment: The manual says nothing, it just says therer are three power slots 4,8,24 pin

Comment: Who is speaking the truth, you (8 & 24) or the manual (4, 8 & 24) ?

Comment: Ah ok guys thanks So I plugged 8pin power cable and was able to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read on pages 24 and 25 of the manual, all 3 power connectors need to be plugged in (they do say "please").

Answer (score 0):

You should connect both.

The 4-pin/8-pin connector powers the CPU as it is quite power hungry, and the 24-pin connector powers the rest of the motherboard. Without either of these you won't get a functional ATX box.